# "The Submission Succeeded.some warnings were found during validation" While uploading iOS App

Tags: app-store, appstore-approval, uploading, application-loader, xcode-organizer

I was trying to upload my iOS app to App Store.After some time i got a message "The Submission Succeeded.some warnings were found during validation" with a list of warnings.
[image]

If anybody knows about these warnings please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This kind of warning you get when there is problem in network while uploading the build to app store.

Answer (score 0):

By this warning did your application get rejected from app store?
As i got the same warnings in my application while uploading to appstore.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) referencing this one if it will help provide context.

Comment: @sona : it got approved from app store.